# How to enable mapping the private property of the entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

At the begining I have to say sorry for my english.

I'm using EntityFramework and code-first way. I have one idea in my head but I dont know how to make it real. I'm not the begginer in programming, but I was always using fluent NHibernate.

I have one entity:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    // This property should be mapped on DB
    private String Surname { get; set; }

    // This one shouldn't be mapped
    public String GetSurname { get { return Surname; } set { Surname = "SomePrefix." + value; }   }
}
```

Question 1. How can I map the private property of the entity?

I can't access this private property in my ovverride of OnModelCreating() in context.

Question 2. How can I disable the mapping of the one public property?

As the result I want to get:
When I try to set the Surname i add the prefix in the begining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity framework does not provide a way of mapping private properties as it needs to read/write values to them, so it must have at least a public get/set for properties.

In answer to your second question you can either use the modelbuilder (my preferred way of describing your mappings as below)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Ignore(u=>u.GetSurname);
```

or add an attribute

```
[NotMapped]
private String Surname { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. But how about first question? How to map a private property?

Comment: @maris, unfortunately you cant properties have to be public and have a get/set why do you want to map a private one anyway

Comment: I want to add a advanced logics(getting and setting) to my property. Something like I want to insert to DB not the entire data but the entire data+prefix.

Comment: @maris So basically you want to mask out some properties from your data model into your application model? My recommendation would be to create a second class for your application model and implement mappers to translate between your application and data model. this will let you map your data as expected to the database while still letting you control your application model.

Comment: I know this way. But the question is - "is it right way?" ) But thx you very much any way. Let's w8 for any other answers, mb someone will tell the other answer.

Comment: @maris there is no 'right way', just what makes sense in your application however feel free to wait for some more answers.