# How to properly trigger lazy load of collection in Entity Framework 5?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm using EF5 (code first) in my application.
I have a table which contains a few lazy loading fields.

```
public class TestEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual TestEntity2 SubEntity2 { get; set; }
    public virtual TestEntity3 SubEntity3 { get; set; }

    private ICollection<SubEntity4> _subEntities;
    public ICollection<SubEntity4> SubEntities
    {
        get { return _subEntities ?? (_subEntities = new Collection<SubEntity4>()); }
        protected set { _subEntities = value; }
    }
}
```

When I'm reading this from database SubEntity2 and SubEntity3 are loading fine but SubEntities collection just won't load and it's always stay Count=0. So I'm forcing load like this:

```
db.Entry(queryResult).Collection(rr => rr.SubEntities).Load();
```

But as I understand this collection should be loaded automatically by EF during the first invocation just like SubEntity2 and SubEntity3. Why isn't it working with collection?

Example of the code I'm using to read database:

```
using (var db = new TestContext(_connection, false))
        {
            var query = from r in db.SubEntities
                        where r.Id == 10
                        select r;

            var queryRes = query.FirstOrDefault();
            if (queryRes != null)
            {
                if (queryRes.FederalRegion != null)
                {
                    // Do something
                }

                foreach (var dbEnt in queryRes.SubEntities)
                {
                    // Do something
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order for lazy-loading to work, EF5 has to do some tricky work. At runtime they create proxy-classes, which are derived from your model classse. Within these proxy classes they override the navigation properties to implement the lazy-loading mechanism.

Your `SubEntity2` and `SubEntity3` properties are virtual, so they can be overridden. Your `SubEntities` property is not virtual - EF5 can't override this property to implement lazy loading for it.

When you make your `SubEntities` property virtual it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. But for some reason I thought that if field isn't marked as virtual it will be always loaded with loading of entity which contains it by default and will not wait for a first invocation.

Comment: @Nelrum If my answer has helped you, feel free to mark it as the accepted answer. :-) - When a property is not marked as virtual, it simply does not support lazy-loading. Eager loading happens only when you explicit demand it.

Answer (score 0):

"Sub-entities" as you describe them (collections) ARE lazy-loaded by their very nature. If you DON'T want them to be lazy-loaded, you should use the `.Include(x=> x.SubEntitiesCollectionName)` extension method.

**EDIT**

**Your class should be like so:**

```
public class TestEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public virtual TestEntity2 SubEntity2 { get; set; }
    public virtual TestEntity3 SubEntity3 { get; set; }    
    public virtual ICollection<SubEntity4> SubEntities { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: They are not lazy loaded, as his code provides no way to enable lazy-loading for this particular property. Please take a look at my answer.

Comment: You added code telling him how his code should look like, but you did not add an explanation what was wrong in the first place. Also I'd rephrase your sentence to use .Include() for preventing lazy-loading. That way you do eager-loading, but you do not disable-lazy loading (it's just not necessary anymore).

Comment: @LiverpoolsNumber9 Ah. Thank you. I'm actually missed virtual keyword and never noticed that. I was trying to find an issue within the code which is reading records, but not in my entities code. My mistake.

Comment: @JustAnotherUserYouMayKnow - it is necessary if you are grabbing non-proxied data into another object. Once you have grabbed the data and the data connection is closed in EF, you cannot lazy-load anything - you get a data connection error and IIS shuts down. I know this because it happened to me last night.

Answer (score 0):

To enable lazy loading you have to make your field `virtual`, it's true. But you have also another problem. You have your `ICollection<SubEntity4>` as `private`. That make your field unaccessible for the mapper. I had the similiar problem, and asked about how to set private field of entity to be visible for a mapper. The answer is - "it's imposible"! Here is a link:

[How to enable mapping the private property of the entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930556/how-to-enable-mapping-the-private-property-of-the-entity)

So just do like this:

```
   public virtual ICollection<SubEntity4> SubEntities {get;set};
```

and remove your property.

Comment: Are you sure about this? As far as I know the properties must be virtual and the properties are overriden to enable lazy-loading. The fields don't matter in this case. Having a private backing field for a virtual public navigation property is no problem.

Comment: hmmm, the idea is interesting but I think it wont works. W8 I will try it.

Comment: Actually I have a public property SubEntities for _subEntities. I've done so in order to implement logic of creation of this collection during first creation of this entity without need to write new Collection<SubEntity4>() each time. Since otherwise it will obviously throw Null object exception.

Comment: Oh, now I get what you wanted. `LiverpoolsNumber9` answer, will work.

Comment: @Maris `public virtual ICollection<SubEntity4> SubEntities {get;set};` I first tried to make it like this but since I want to fill SubEntities collection before I save TestEntity to database and save it all together later I was getting NullReferenceException when I'm tied to add new items to it. Which is totally expected since there was no collection object to add to.